LVM device gone after unmounting
By accident, I unmounted an LVM device. Then, I unmounted the actual disk I wanted to unmount. But now, I'd like to reset the configuration, but when mounting my disk mount /data, it tells me that
mount: /data: special device /dev/storage/storageVolumeLVM does not exist.

The device /dev/storage is indeed gone. How can I get it back? vgs still lists my storage VG.

lvdisplay lists the volume groups along with their device path.

In my case, the device was gone because I previously deactivated the local volume. So,
lvchange -a y /dev/storage/storageVolumeLMV

brought it back. Then, mounting worked again.
